# How Do You Connect Javascript To a Submit Button To Code the Text

Tags: javascript

For some reason, it is unable to connect to the Javascript. I am trying to automatically decode words into something decipherable. If you are asking where I got the huge encode application, I got it from a website and this is being used for education purposes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="input" value='Nothing Important' id="ID">
Convert Into Code: <input type="text" name="user" id="XD">
<input type="submit" value="Code" onclick="Input()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript:

```
window.input = function() {
function base64_encode (data) {
var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
ac = 0,
enc = "",
tmp_arr = [];

if (!data) {
return data;
}

do { 
o1 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
o2 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
o3 = data.charCodeAt(i++);

bits = o1 << 16 | o2 << 12 | o3;

h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
h2 = bits >> 12 & 0x3f;
h3 = bits >> 6 & 0x3f;
h4 = bits >> 2 & 0x3f;
tmp_arr[ac++] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
} while (i < data.length);

enc = tmp_arr.join('');

var r = data.length % 3;

return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 4);

}
alert(base64_encode (XD));
};
```

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive, `Input()` is not `input()`

Comment: check your browser console to see the errrors

Comment: The question is unclear; as far as I can make it, the poster is asking us to "fix this code I do not understand, which I have just copied and pasted from some website". Voting to close.

Comment: I am trying to code words in the text into a random language by pressing the submit button. Is that so hard to learn?

Comment: The Problem: ' Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'charCodeAt' '

Comment: @user2103896, the reason is you need to get the value of the element so look at point 2) in my answer and then look at the piece of code just above the `alert`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes:

1) Your `onclick` value `Input()` needs to be `input()`.

2) You need to get the value from the input field by referencing the DOM object and then getting the value.

3) You don't need a form to do what you want to do here.

4) You should really use a label for the input field.

5) I haven't changed the way you create the function in your code but you know you can just do `function input() {...}` and it will be globally accessible without having to explicitly use `window`.

6) Make sure you end your input tags.

7) If you aren't using a form then you should use `type="button"` on the `input` field instead of `submit` but it'll still work either way.

[jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8h93K/2/).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="XD">Convert Into Code:</label>
        <input type="text" name="user" id="XD" />
        <input type="button" value="Code" onclick="input()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.input = function()
{
    function base64_encode (data)
    {
        var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
        var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0, ac = 0, enc = "", tmp_arr = [];
        if (!data)
        {
            return data;
        }

        do
        { 
            o1 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
            o2 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
            o3 = data.charCodeAt(i++);

            bits = o1 << 16 | o2 << 12 | o3;

            h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
            h2 = bits >> 12 & 0x3f;
            h3 = bits >> 6 & 0x3f;
            h4 = bits >> 2 & 0x3f;

            tmp_arr[ac++] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2)
                          + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
        }
        while (i < data.length);

        enc = tmp_arr.join('');

        var r = data.length % 3;

        return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 4);
    }

    var XD = document.getElementById('XD').value;
    alert(base64_encode(XD));
};
```